# Automatically check if dependencies are up to date

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm looking for a tool that will check if the library dependencies in my SBT build definition are up to date. I've heard that such a tool exists, but my Google skills are failing me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SBT plugin](https://github.com/rtimush/sbt-updates-plugin) from Roman Timushev